# Twitter Tweet Button don't use built in URL Shortener?

Tags: twitter, twitter-api

I am using the following code to generate a Tweet Button on my site.

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://mysite.com/asdf" data-text="Description about my the page" data-count="horizontal">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js">
```

Works great, however when twitter I click on the button like a user would to tweet, it automatically shortens the URL using their **http://t.co** domain.  I do not want this to happen as the data-url is going to be short enough as is.

Basically I want to still use the Tweet Button at some level, but don't want Twitter automatically shortening my URLs.  Is this possible?  Is there a different button/script I should look at?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem can be handled by using "#" for data-url.

ex:

```
  data-url="#"

 data-related="anywhere:The Javascript API"

  data-count="vertical">Tweet</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Twitter is moving all links to their t.co service. http://support.twitter.com/entries/109623 There are a few ways around it today, but in the future they will all be t.co, but the t.co will be hidden.